# Get fields values in the view

Tags: views, entities

I am new on Drupal and I need to update an existing **Drupal 7** website.

The website is multi-domains, multi-languages.

Getting the **views fields values** makes me a big headache!

---

The existing code of the website is like this:

In the folder **templates**:

Each template of the website has a file like: `views-view-unformatted--some-name.tpl.php`

And the to print the fields values, the code is similar to this:

```
<?php
$idInFieldCollection = $view->result[0]->field_field_a_name[0]['raw']['value'];
$item = $view->result[0]->field_field_a_name[0];
$value = $item['rendered']['entity']['field_collection_item'][$idInFieldCollection]['field_the_field_needed']['#items'][0]['value'];
?>
<span><?php print($value); ?></span>
```

This process seems huge!

And finding the path for each field value requires to use `kpr()` and explore the view object.

I don't understand so much yet all I read about Drupal, could you guys let me know if there is an easier way. With getters for example ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Entity](https://drupal.org/project/entity) module. in this module no matter what the language of the website is you can use `entity_metadata_wrapper` command to get the fields value. here is an example of my project where `field_article_writer` and `title` are fields of article content type:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
switch ($variables['node']->type){
    case 'article':
        $suggest = "page__node__article";
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$variables['node']);
        $variables['title']= $wrapper->title->value();
        $variables['writer']= $wrapper->field_article_writer->value();
        break;
    }
}
```

Now in `page--node--article.tpl.php`, `$title` and `$writer` hold their correspondent value.

Comment: If you believe this is the right answer please check as the accepted for people who will read your question in the future.